# Difference between ObjectId on client and server in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I was learning Meteor.js recently and was making a simple test app. There's an array of `ids` of a collection I save in `Session`.

I have two collections: `Workouts` and `AssignedWorkouts`. `AssignedWorkouts` have a field which store the `id` of a `Workouts`.

`Session.get("assignedWorkouts")` acts differently on my system and on server.

On server, `Workouts._id` is an object (`e._ObjectId`) but on my machine it is a string.

Here's from test4faceyspacey.meteor.com's console,

```
 Workouts.findOne()._id
 e._ObjectID {_str: "53188350f47ed90eed042df2", toString: function, equals: function, clone: function, typeName: function…}
 typeof Workouts.findOne()._id
 "object"
```

this is from my system's console

```
Workouts.findOne()._id
"58pa4pp3Lgwef7vGA"
typeof Workouts.findOne()._id
"string"
```

Any explanation about why it is like this? I asked some senior devs about this but they say they never had such an issue.

Due to this I need to maintain two different versions of code.

Please check deployed app here:
http://test4faceyspacey.meteor.com/

Code here: https://github.com/channikhabra/meteor-workouts-app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you inserted the document from Meteor, it gets the string id by default.  If you insert a document from the mongo command line, or from some mongo ui, it gets an object as id by default.

You can override this behavior in meteor, but I'd recommend you try the string.  You do lose a timestamp that is present in the object id, but I'd tell you to use an explicit timestamp anyway.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I did inserted all the rows from mongo cli on the server. I re-deployed the app with different url for testing and it works now i.e now the `ids` are strings.

Comment: How can I ovverride this behavior? I am trying to find an object in the database that was inserted externally, so it uses ObjectId() for the _id, but Meteor.Collection.ObjectID("value of the Object id") returns _str:"my id", instead of type ObjectId